# What is current model matrix defined as and how does it differ if a shader is applied to a 3D object or a camera's render texture?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, shader

I am trying to compute depth in unity and while unity's ml-image-synthesis library supports rendering depth textures, I would like to get depth for virtual points that will not render on to the screen. https://bitbucket.org/Unity-Technologies/ml-imagesynthesis/src/master/Assets/ImageSynthesis/Shaders/UberReplacement.shader

I've already pieced together that it uses COMPUTE_DEPTH_01 to get the eye to far depth and converts it to near to far by using a prebuilt function. And I've already done some basic test on generating model matrices using `transform.localtoworldmatrix` and view matrices  using `Camera.worldToCameraMatrix`. But if I want to replicate COMPUTE_DEPTH_01 which is defined as  `-(mul( UNITY_MATRIX_MV, v.vertex ).z * _ProjectionParams.w)`, I need help determining what the current and view model are as `UNITY_MATRIX_MV` is [current model * view matrix](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-UnityShaderVariables.html) and I don't know if current model refers to the camera's current model or the object in the camera's view current model.

Answer (score 0):

The current model refers to the current object that is being rendered in the scene.

In a very simple Unity project with a camera, a light, and a cube, the cube's position within the world would be the model matrix. In a more complex scene with numerous objects, the model matrix would be the transform matrix for whichever object is being currently transformed.

Thus, the model matrix, camera matrix, and view matrix transform's the model's vertex positions from its own local coordinates to world coordinates (model matrix) and then into the camera space (view matrix), and finally projected "through the camera lens" and onto a flat plane (projection matrix).

Comment: So in the bitbucket I linked, when it renders the depth using COMPUTE_DEPTH_01 the current model changes based on what's it is rendering? So if I want to determine the depth of a virual point, I would just multiply the "current model" of the point and the camera's view matrix to get my depth

Comment: For your virtual point, if you know the point's world coordinates (their absolute position within the world), you can just directly transform it into camera space.

Comment: The rationale of the current model transform is an object whose vertices are fixed relative to some arbitrary origin, like the set of vertices for a car. When the car moves, it makes sense to move the car's origin within world space, while the car's individual vertex positions remain static relative to its own local origin. The model matrix transforms these local vertices into world coordinates. This can be extended as sub-objects, like wheels of the car. The model matrix for the wheels accounts for both the car's transform and the wheel's transform relative to its parent, the car.